# Error al ejecutar generador de codigo creando controladores en ASP.NET MVC

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc

[image: Error]

He probado con volver a generar el proyecto, a limpiar la resolución, 
re-compilar y aun sigue el error. favor de ayudar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya encontre la solucion: hacer click derecho en la solución del proyecto y elegir descargar proyecto y luego volver a cargar el proyecto.